# Recursion - Finding the longest string in a list

Tags: python, recursion

Write a function recursiveLongestString(lst) that takes a list of strings as input
and returns the longest string in the list. You may assume the list contains at least one
element and there will not be a tie. This function must use recursion in a meaningful
way; a solution that uses a loop or built-in max functions will receive no points.
For example, `recursiveLongestString(["a", "bb", "ccc"])` returns `"ccc"`, and
`recursiveLongestString(["hi", "its", "fantastic", "here"])` returns
`"fantastic"`.

This is my code so far:

```
def recursiveLongestString(lst):

    if(len(lst)==1):
        return(lst[0])
    else:
        smaller= recursiveLongestString(lst[1:])
        if len(lst[0])<len(lst[1]):
                return smaller
        else:
            return lst[0] + smaller
```

I knos why its wrong, but cant seem to find a solution. Pls help

Comment: You are actually *very* close. The idea is correct, you just need to change the comparison and final return. The comparison should compare the lengths of the first element and the length of the recursion result (i.e. `smaller`). Then the final result should only return `lst[0]` -- there's not reason to tack on more.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. In the if/else you should only ever return a single string because thats what you want `recursive_longest` to ultimately return. Try this:

```
def recursive_longest(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]

    current = lst[0]
    longest = recursive_longest(lst[1:])
    
    if len(current) < len(longest):
        return longest 
    else:
        return current
```

**Bonus for you:** You might also want to add an extra if statement at the beginning to decide what you might do if the list that was provided is empty.

Comment: you mean `if len(current) > len(longest):`

Comment: @flaxon I did have a bug initially. Perhaps you haven't reloaded.

Comment: Worth pointing out that you also improved the variable name, as `smaller` was somewhat confusing. I guess they meant "result for the smaller list", but could be misunderstood as "smaller string". Maybe `longest_in_rest` would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

For a meaningful use, you could split the list in two and recurse left and right subsets of the list to determine two longest strings and then compare those two for the final result:

```
def recursiveLongestString(lst,start=0,end=None):
    if end is None: end = len(lst)-1 # initial range is whole list 
    if start==end: return lst[start] # base condition, stops recursion
    mid = (start+end)//2             # split index
    maxLeft  = recursiveLongestString(lst,start,mid) # longest on the left
    maxRight = recursiveLongestString(lst,mid+1,end) # longest on the rigth
    return maxLeft if len(maxLeft)>len(maxRight) else maxRight


recursiveLongestString(["hi", "its", "fantastic", "here"])

'fantastic'
```

*This has the advantage of not hitting the recursion depth limit when your list has close to 1000 items. Also, it doesn't create any copies of the list content*

The reductive approach can be made more compact by transmitting the longest string down the recursion calls using a defaulted parameter:

```
def recursiveLongestString(L,S=""):
    return recursiveLongestString(L[1:],(L[0],S)[len(S)>len(L[0])]) if L else S
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more efficient version, as your `lst[1:]` takes linear time and space and thus your whole procedure takes *quadratic* time and space. This one only takes *linear* time and space:

```
def recursiveLongestString(lst):
    if not lst:
        return ''
    s = lst.pop()
    t = recursiveLongestString(lst)
    lst.append(s)
    return s if len(s) > len(t) else t
```